# Find how many rows were created per minute over the last hour

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to do some statistics gathering with data in a Postgres db and have run into some trouble.

Basically I have a row called `posts` with a `created_at` timestamp and I want to be able to find out how many posts were created on a minute-by-minute basis, 15m basis, daily, etc. to generate some charts.

Here's what I have so far

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    minute_series.minute,
    count(c.minute) OVER (PARTITION BY c.minute) AS count
FROM
    (SELECT
        generate_series(
            date_trunc('minute', localtimestamp - interval '1 hour'),
            localtimestamp, '1 min')
        AS minute FROM posts) minute_series
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT date_trunc('minute', "created_at") AS minute FROM posts) c
    USING (minute)
ORDER BY 1;
```

which yields the following results:

```
       minute        | count
---------------------+-------
 2015-08-26 10:17:00 | 33869
 2015-08-26 10:18:00 |  6158
 2015-08-26 10:19:00 |  9237
 2015-08-26 10:20:00 |     0
 2015-08-26 10:21:00 |  9237
 2015-08-26 10:22:00 |  6158
 2015-08-26 10:23:00 |  9237
 2015-08-26 10:24:00 |     0
 2015-08-26 10:25:00 |     0
 2015-08-26 10:26:00 |  3079
 2015-08-26 10:27:00 |     0
 2015-08-26 10:28:00 |  9237
 2015-08-26 10:29:00 |     0
 2015-08-26 10:30:00 |     0
 2015-08-26 10:31:00 |  6158
 2015-08-26 10:32:00 |     0
 2015-08-26 10:33:00 |  6158
 2015-08-26 10:34:00 |  3079
```

The format is exactly what I'm looking for, but the actual counts for some reason are incorrect (I only have ~3k posts in the database right now, so it'd be impossible for 6k to be created in the span of 1 minute...)

Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try selecting `generate_sequence` without `FROM` clause, otherwise you are duplicating minutes as many times as you have posts in the database.

```
SELECT
    minute_series.minute,
    count(c.minute) AS count -- Better to replace with ID
FROM
    (SELECT
        generate_series(
            date_trunc('minute', localtimestamp - interval '1 hour'),
            localtimestamp, '1 min')
        AS minute) minute_series -- NO FROM here
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT date_trunc('minute', "created_at") AS minute FROM posts) c
    USING (minute)
GROUP BY minute_series.minute
ORDER BY 1;
```